# How not to include empty elements in SQL Server for xml

Tags: sql-server, xml

Given the following query (which is part of a much bigger query):

```
select  
    (select szamlatetel_id as SzamlatetelId,
            kiert_eredm as KiertEredm
     from vv_kiert K where K.vv_fej_id = 3
     order by K.id
     for xml raw('Kiertekeles'), TYPE)
```

This query returns this result:

```
NULL
```

But there should be an empty result set.

I do not want to see this element at all because the schema says, if I have this element named within the XML, I MUST specify some other required fields. Therefore, my schema validation fails.

How to return an empty result set (not NULL)

The above query is included in that query:

```
select  
    (select szamlatetel_id as SzamlatetelId,
            kiert_eredm as KiertEredm
     from vv_kiert K 
     where K.vv_fej_id = 3
     order by K.id
     for xml raw('Kiertekeles'), TYPE) 
for xml raw('Kiertekelesek'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

Which itself is included in a way bigger query.

I do not want to see the Kiertekelesek element at all.

Instead of that I see this:

```
<Kiertekelesek />
```

How to avoid creating that Kiertekelesek  element?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Well... not. (Sensible data) The idea is that the vv_kiert table is empty. So no Kiertekeles and Kiertekelesek element should appear in the final xml. This is more or less the same as: 
select (select 1 where 1=0) actually I would like to see an empty result, not NULL

Comment: Doesn't need to be real data. It's hard to help without knowing what we're dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner query already does what you are asking.

```
 select szamlatetel_id as SzamlatetelId,
        kiert_eredm as KiertEredm
 from vv_kiert K where K.vv_fej_id = 3
 order by K.id
 for xml raw('Kiertekeles')
```

with a result-set it gives

```
<Kiertekeles szamlatetel_id="12 />
```

with no result-set it gives zero rows

Here is a full example with a temp tale and data to demonstrate the solution.  Please try it yourself.

```
CREATE TABLE #vv_kiert(
    id int NOT NULL,
    szamlatetel_id int  NOT NULL,
    kiert_eredm varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    vv_fej_id int NULL
) 
GO

--example 1 with 1 (non-matching) row
INSERT INTO #vv_kiert VALUES (1, 1, 'example1', 0)

-- your original query, yields 1 row, 1 col: "NULL"
select  
  (select szamlatetel_id as SzamlatetelId,
        kiert_eredm as KiertEredm
  from #vv_kiert K where K.vv_fej_id = 3
  order by K.id
  for xml raw('Kiertekeles'), TYPE)

--example 2 with 2 rows (1 matching)
INSERT INTO #vv_kiert VALUES (2, 2, 'example2', 3)

-- your original query
select  
  (select szamlatetel_id as SzamlatetelId,
        kiert_eredm as KiertEredm
  from #vv_kiert K where K.vv_fej_id = 3
  order by K.id
  for xml raw('Kiertekeles'), TYPE)
--yields 1 row, 1 col: <Kiertekeles SzamlatetelId="2" KiertEredm="example2" />

--example 3 with an empty table
DELETE FROM #vv_kiert 

-- your original query, yields 1 row 1 col: "NULL"
select  
  (select szamlatetel_id as SzamlatetelId,
        kiert_eredm as KiertEredm
  from #vv_kiert K where K.vv_fej_id = 3
  order by K.id
  for xml raw('Kiertekeles'), TYPE)

--My Solution, yields zero rows, like you requested
 select szamlatetel_id as SzamlatetelId,
        kiert_eredm as KiertEredm
 from #vv_kiert K where K.vv_fej_id = 3
 order by K.id
 for xml raw('Kiertekeles')

-- done. clean up.
DROP TABLE #vv_kiert
```

If you are getting a different result, please modify your question to include a data example like this one.

Comment: No, it does not. If there are data within vv_kiert corresponding to K.vv_fej_id = 3 then you are right. But the problem is when there is no corresponding record I do not want to appear the Kiertekeles element at all

Comment: That is interesting enough not how SQL works. The SQL part of the query still shows the rows - you can and should filter them out there.

Comment: Gabor, I had to guess at your data, based on what you showed in your example.  I updated my answer to show what I understand about your data structure.  If there is a misunderstanding, please copy/paste my data into your question and modifiy it so it is more accurate. I think that should help us understand things better.

Comment: @tgolisch I vote yours up, Mainly for the good guessing ;-) You might read the comment below my answer. One more reason to vote on this helpful contribution.

Answer (score 0):

XML will return *no element*, when this is `NULL`, but your inner query will return an empty element, which is not `NULL`, thus the outer `SELECT` will be displayed as you've found out. That is *by design*.

You can out-trick this, by using a CTE to perform your query and force the query to be `NULL` in total by placing a `WHERE` to the outer query. Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SomeData VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('A');

WITH cte AS
(
     select SomeData as SzamlatetelId
     from @tbl K 
     where K.SomeData = 'B' --try this with 'A' to get a result
)
--the query will use the cte instead of the actual query
select  
    (select *
     from cte
     for xml raw('Kiertekeles'), TYPE) 
--and there will be no result, if the cte has no rows
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte)>0
for xml raw('Kiertekelesek'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

Comment: Although this could be a good approach, but in my particular case this would not work, as the real query is very complicated (as the XML schema is complicated as well (lots of different deeply embedded elements and theirs attribs). So until I've found a better solution, I'm converting the result into a varchar(max) and strip out all the empty elements. Not nice, but at least I get to the result.

Comment: @Gabor, with more than 3 years on SO and more than 600 points on your account you should know, that a question is answered as it is asked. Both answers try to fill the lacking information by guessing. Both answers are helpful and there is a solution which fully solves the issue provided by you. We cannot know the details behind... What you should do: Up-vote helpful contributions and accept the best answer (this is up to you of course). You might place a new question with an appropriate sample. That is the SO-way to say *thank you*...